# what is queryset = super().get_queryset()?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

These two pieces of code are identical

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(.........)
```

and

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post

    def get_queryset(self):
        return post.filter(.........)
```

what is this line actually do `queryset = super().get_queryset()` and what will happen in the absence of this line?

Comment: `super().get_queryset()` calls the `get_queryset()` method of its parent class and if multiple parents then it follows MRO to determine which class method to call.

Comment: and what will happen in the absence of this line -> the function `get_queryset()` will not be inherited from parent class, only the newly written function will be execuded

Comment: @VishalSingh what will `get_queryset()` of its parent class returns

Comment: http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/#get_queryset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are not identical, or at least not *per se*. `super()` is used to obtain the implementation of `get_queryset` that is the next in the *method resolution order (MRO)*. If classes would have only one baseclass, you could think of this as the parent class, but in Python *multiple inheritance* is allowed, and thus the rules of the MRO are more compilcated.

Regardless, `super().get_queryset`, will thus call the `get_queryset` how it was implemented for the `DetailView` class here. This is an important difference, since the basic `get_queryset()` method will *first* look for a `queryset` attribute, and if that is not present, it will use `model._default_manager.all()`.

If you thus specify a `queryset` attribute, the two are not identical, For example if we define a `queryset` with:

```
class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = models.Post
    queryset = models.Post.objects.filter(active=True)
```

then your implementation with `super().get_queryset()` will only show active `Post`s, whereas the implementation with `Post.objects.filter(…)` will show all posts that satisfy the filter, but are not se active `Post`s.

If you would work with *mixins*, then it will, depending in what order you use the mixins, call the `get_queryset()` of one of these mixins, and thus can result in more sophisticated filtering.